# Ignore first row in R

Tags: r

How do I do in R, to ignore the first row of a data set and a second turn the column names?

I am currently reading a file that sometimes has garbage on the first or second line, and I am looking for a way to resolve this.

Comment: typically there's a `skip` argument in data reading functions. consult the help files for more information

Comment: What kind of file are you reading?  What package/function are you reading it with?